# Несколько ссылок на одном картинке

Tags: php, html, css

Здрасте. Мне задали задачку сделать несколько ссылок на одном фото. Чтобы при наведении высвечилось разные места картинки. Например на этом сайте: http://kohitobon.tj/select_etazh.html . Как можно сделать такое. Куда копать где учить. Благодарю за внимание.

Comment: конкретно на этом сайте - SVG

Comment: еще смотри в сторону Карты-изображения

Comment: карты MAP не подойдет. он не высвечивает. курсы или что нибудь есть на такой SVG? SVG же обширен.

Answer (score 0):

[position: absolute](http://htmlbook.ru/css/position)

В помощь! Есть возможность реализации через [map>](http://htmlbook.ru/html/MAP)

Comment: map как вариант не расматриваю извините. забыл упоминать в вопросе.